# Isomorphism from a non trivial ring onto the polynomial ring over itself

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, polynomial-rings

Does there exist a non-trivial ring $R$ such that $R\cong R[X]$? ($R[X]$ denotes the polynomial ring over $R$). If not, how does one prove it? Else, an example of such a ring and the respective isomorphism is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: You can take $R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\dots ]$.

Comment: Thank you pax :). That works. didn't cross my mind.

Comment: I’m sure there is a duplicate answering with the infinite polynomial ring but I haven’t found it yet. I’m linking for the time being to another interesting distinct example.